# Oracle SQL Update by rownum

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, row-number, rownum

I have the data in the following format:

```
ORD_NO  ITEM  FULFILL_ID
SA1     1000     1 
SA1     2000     2
SA2     2000     1
SA2     3000     2
SA2     9000     3
```

I want to fill in the values for the column FULFILL_ID, which should start with 1 and increase till the number of rows for one particular ORD NO, as I have filled above.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

This is what `ROW_NUMBER()` does:

```
select ord_no, item,
       row_number() over (partition by ord_no order by item) as fulfill_id
from table t;
```

This returns the value as a query.  A slightly different query is needed for an update.

EDIT:

The update can be done like this:

```
update table t
    set fulfill_id = (select count(*)
                      from table t2
                      where t2.ord_no = t.order_no and
                            t2.item <= t.item
                     );
```

This version assumes that `item` is different for the same values of `ord_no`.

Comment: The Item can be same for the orders. I need to update every row as different number.

Comment: I believe that Oracle's performance sucks when updating from correlated sub-queries in this way.

Answer (score 2):

you can use merge statement for this

```
merge into table1 t3 using
(
select ord_no, item,
       row_number() over (partition by ord_no order by item) as fulfill_id
from table1 
) s
on 
(t3.ORD_NO=s.ORD_NO and t3.ITEM=s.ITEM)
when matched then
update set t3.FULFILL_ID=s.fulfill_id
```

Comment: Item might not be the unique for any particular Order No.
how to generically update fulfill_id based on the number of rows under than OrderNo?

Comment: if 100 rows are there with one ord_no it will give numbers from 1 to 100 and updates the fulfill_id. we are partitioning on ord_no column.

Comment: This query gives me the error missing SET keyword ---
merge into table1 t3 using
(
select ord_no, item,
       row_number() over (partition by ord_no order by item) as fulfill_id
from table1 
) s
ON 
(t3.ord_no=s.ord_no and t3.ITEM=s.ITEM)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
update OMS_DUMMY set t3.FULFILL_ID=s.fulfill_id;

Comment: No need to use OMS_DUMMY. it will update columns of table1. Please check syntactical errors. Table name u mentioned after merge keyword will effect by update statement.

Comment: I get this error now:
Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90792/discussion-between-imran-hemani-and-tarun).

Comment: I guess You're  trying to to update the same row of the target table multiple times. Make sure your update does not update the same record more than once.